# Printing Strings

Tags: c#, string, printing

I am working on a program in which I need to print out a string, I have the string ready, I just need to know how to print, I've never done it so i don't know where to start any ideas?
this is what I have so far but I don't know where to go from here

```
PrintDocument output = new PrintDocument();
output.DocumentName = "Test Results";
```

Comment: Do you mean print as in print a document on a printer?  Have you looked into any third-party libraries that handle printing?

Comment: Also, there's information on MSDN about using the PrintDocument class if you want to stick with that:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx

Comment: try this too http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/453871/Simple-Receipt-Like-Printing-Using-the-Csharp-Prin

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of 'Print' is pretty vague. The most common meaning of print in this part of the internet is to print or display text to the console or command window.

So, if you want to print to a console window you use methods on the System.Console class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx

For example:

```
String yourname = "Mr. Nice";
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", yourname);
```

would display:

> Hello Mr. Nice

Comment: as in print it out on a printer

Answer (score 1):

You can print with `Console.WriteLine("text")` to standard output.

Have a look at string interpolation to make adding variables to string far easier. This was introduced in C# 6 and has following syntax.

`Console.Writeline($"I am {cool}");` where `cool` is the variable name :)

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
public class Print
{
    PrintDocument myPrintDocument = new PrintDocument();

    public void ShowPrintDialog()
    {
        PrintDialog myDialog = new PrintDialog();
        myDialog.Document = myPrintDocument;
        if(myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            Print();
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Your String To Print In Document", this.Font, Brushes.Red, new PointF());
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I couldn't get this example to compile.  You have override on `OnPrintPage`, but class `Print` doesn't inherit from anything but object, which does not expose a virtual method OnPrintPage.  Also, your method `Print()` is not declared anywhere.  Did you test this out before posting?